# SMTP mail sending not working in server

Tags: c#, .net, smtp, smtpclient, windows-firewall

I have an SMTP setting (with SSL enabled) which works when I try it in my local system. However the same gives Connection Timeout error when used in server.

I have checked and confirmed that

1. proxy server is not enabled
2. necessary ports are open on firewall settings
3. antivirus is disabled

I am against a wall now as I don't know how to get this working and have been behind this for the past one week.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar situation with my SMTP provider (Mandrill/MailChimp). In my case the server was able to send email while I was facing timeout errors in my local computer. I solved the issue by changing the DNS addresses, and it is working now.